# Is there away that a dropdown data validation box can self populate an answer if a particular cells contains text?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been working on a spreadsheet which a few people on this site have helped with, (Thank You).
I have a series of dependent dropdown boxes.
These show the Type, Category, Product Type and finally description.
For example, Type could be 'Shopping', Category could give me a list of "Fresh, Frozen, Cleaning" and then Product Type could be "Fruit", Description would then provide me with a list of options.

I have been asked by a colleague, that if we knew the item code of what we wanted, could it be placed in to a cell, and then all the dropdowns auto populate?
Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks

Comment: You could use a `VlookUp` instead, if you need to use dependent dropdown list, a simple search will throw you [this](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=excel+dependent+dropdown+list)

Comment: I may not have explained this very well, I have already created the dependent drops downs, they use offset formulas etc so that with each drop down they provide the correct dependent, however what I was wondering, was that if someone put a code in, could excel ignore the dropdowns and populate the cells with data using the vlookup straight away.

Comment: That could only be achievable by VBA, not just excel formulas Pete.

Comment: Thats fine, I have been testing VBA and learning bits as I go along, but this I imagine is a little complex, do you have any ideas on how it could be done?

Comment: You'd need to use the `Worksheet_Change()` event under your worksheet object. There check that the cell changed is the one where the code goes, if so, trigger a procedure which will fill the cells with it's data. You'd fill them with the value, since you can write a value if it exists on the list and you don't want to delete the dropdown list.

Comment: Thank you for this, would it be at all possible for you to provide me with a sample code just so I can see what you mean and I will then test it on my worksheet? I am very new to VBA, I would really appreciate this

Comment: Try using the vlookup directly on the cells while recording the macro so you get the formulas. then read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220333/how-to-change-cell-value-using-worksheet-change-event-without-triggering-a-secon) to understand how the `Worksheet_Change` works.

Comment: Thanks Ill give it a go and see how far I get

Comment: Hi Damian, I was wondering if you might be able to help me further, I am struggling to understand this VBA code. the vlookup I have is like this "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("IWA",B61)),INDEX(IWA!F:F,MATCH(B61,IWA!E:E,0)),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("IWK",F54)),"IWK = YES","NO"))" the idea is that it depends on the text of the code the user enters, as there are 2 price lists to lookup. I am really not sure how to do what I want via the VBA method you have suggested, I have looked on Google to try and understand. do you have any suggestions?